# What are some good GUI diff and merge applications available for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

What are some alternatives to WinMerge and the pros and cons of each?

Comment: See also: [Does Ubuntu have a graphical software to compare and merge differences in files?](http://askubuntu.com/q/510724/178596)

Comment: You can use WinMerge in Ubuntu with WineHQ. I am using it for long time this way.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The best I like is [Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/)

There are many choices available though. As a vim fan I find myself using vimdiff, kompare for the kde crowd - there also some paid version that have linux versions like [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) . The pros/cons depends on what you're looking for/looking to do.

vimdiff is great because you can run it from a terminal, over an ssh connection, and if you already use vim, you get to keep your tools/config options.

Meld has a pretty clean user interface, and does three way and directory diffs. You'll have to try a couple and see which does the job as you're expecting them to do for your own needs.

To install [Meld[image: Meld app page]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/meld/) from the Ubuntu repos, you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install meld
```

You can then pick the files/folders to compare, and compare them:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I use meld a lot, it's support for svn, mercurial and git is great.

Comment: Meld is awesome, its included as the default merge tool in RabbitVCS

Comment: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Meld describes some stability issues and notes the lack of (auto) merging features.

Comment: I must say that this one pulls in a LOT of dependencies:  libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common libglade2-0 libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libgtksourceview2.0-0 libgtksourceview2.0-common python-glade2
  python-gnome2 python-gtksourceview2 python-pyorbit

Comment: Note that current Meld in Ubuntu has a serious bug with remote files:

Comment: Meld I think is what most *common* users would expect. Nice gui, easy to use.

Answer (score 29):

Another one is [diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/)

[image]

It is free, crossplatform (written in python), has source code highlight, can interact with many version control tools.

Comment: I was looking for a diff tool that would allow pasting bits of text into the right and left panes. This is the first one I found. +1

Comment: This one unfortunately does not take two directories on the command line. It looks like it only compares files, not dirs? This makes it less useful imo.

Comment: +1 as this solves my problem where I'm running LXDE and Lubuntu. I love Meld, but would have to install a bunch of gnome libraries which would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Supports drag-n-drop unlike Meld.

Comment: Cannt compare folders I guess

Comment: (+) allows to paste text into window panes,  but (-) does not word wrap, and (-) latest release is 0.4.8 from 2014-07-18, so development probably is indefinitely on hold.

Comment: @Bojangles actually, `Meld` can do it too - it's just not clear UI - you have to go to "File Comparison" (or click it) and then button "Blank Comparison" displays 2 boxes to paste in texts :-) ; @Artem Pelenitsyn latest version does support drag&drop (both files and text selections)

Answer (score 18):

### Kdiff3

Is a pretty good 3 way merge tool.

[image]

Some of its features are:

- compares or merges two or three text input files or directories,
- shows the differences line by line and character by character (!),
- provides an automatic merge-facility and
- an integrated editor for comfortable solving of merge-conflicts,
- supports Unicode, UTF-8 and other codecs, autodetection via byte-order-mark "BOM"
- supports KIO on KDE (allows accessing ftp, sftp, fish, smb etc.),
- Printing of differences,
- Manual alignment of lines,
- Automatic merging of version control history ($Log$),
- and has an intuitive graphical user interface.
- Windows-Explorer integration Diff-Ext-for-KDiff3 - shell extension included in installer
  KDE-Konqueror service menu plugin

Comment: I love Kdiff3 and I have used it for years, but it uses Qt and sometimes can get weird in non-KDE environments. That said, it may work better or worse for some people :)