# Does Ubuntu have any graphical software to compare and merge differences in files?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, diff, merge

I want to compare two or more files and merge the differences as needed. I was using Windows but now working on Ubuntu 12.04.

In windows "Beyond compare" made my work easier, but since I shifted to Linux, I am not able to find any tool or software like beyond compare in windows. Please tell me if you know any. Thank you very much.

Comment: There are `comm`, `join`, `uniq`, `diff`, `sort`, `grep` etc commands available for **text-processing** (visit `man` page for more detail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use Beyond Compare on Linux, they have a Linux port.

Go to http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php and download one of the debian packages.

Tried it on 14.04; [these instructions](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_linux_install) work just fine. It also works without gdebi, if you `sudo apt-get install libice6 libsm6 libxft2 libxt6`.

[image: Beyond Compare interface]

Answer (score 2):

`fldiff` might be what you search. It's in the offical repositories. Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install fldiff
```

Another one is `diffuse`:

```
sudo apt-get install diffuse
```