# Graphical Diff viewer that supports LXDE (Lubuntu)

Tags: lubuntu, ide, diff

I've installed a fresh copy of Lubuntu on my netbook for the purpose of development "on-the-go". I've installed most of the tools I need except for one handy one: [Meld Diff Viewer](http://meldmerge.org/).

Meld required Gnome libraries to be installed and since LXDE isn't Gnome, I would need to install a ton of libraries just to have Meld which defeats the purpose of a light weight operating system setup.

Is there a graphic diff viewer that is supported by LXDE?

Answer (score 3):

I decided to go another quick google search as my first one didn't give me any decent results. I found another [question](https://askubuntu.com/a/3013/5368) about graphical diff viewers that mentioned [diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/). No extra libraries were needed for installation. One caveat - apparently, it doesn't support directory comparison but I have yet to try it out so maybe the newest version does?