# Diff tool that can compare texts without having to create text files

Tags: software-recommendation

I use Meld but I always have to create two text files to use it. I simply want to copy paste text and compare locally without having to create any files.

Comment: What kind of text?  From where?  What is your expected workflow?

Comment: Just two texts that I copy and paste. The tool should compare them and highlight the differences. How Meld works but without having to create two text files.

Comment: I'm using Meld with New Comparison, File comparison, Blank Comparison, then paste two buffers - left and right,  for years. Do not see any porblems.

Comment: omg, I didn't know this is possible. Thank you.

Comment: LOL, who in their right mind names clipboard text comparison "Blank Comparison" , to be clear in latest version you have to click the File comparison button (if not visible, go to File => New Comparison) - then the Blank Comparison button becomes enabled => click it => and then paste your text to left and right boxes :-) 
BTW: More tools: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2946/what-are-some-good-gui-diff-and-merge-applications-available-for-ubuntu